# NGINX: Redirect all requests to my localhost port to https/SSL

Tags: node.js, ssl, express, nginx, https

I have a NodeJS server running on `localhost:8080`. It's an HTTPS server, rather than HTTP.

Because of this the site does not work when accessing `http://localhost8080`, only works with `https://localhost:8080`.

I'd like to use NGINX to redirect all traffic coming to `localhost:8080/whatever` to `https://localhost:8080/whatever`.

I've tried:

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name 127.0.0.1;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

to no avail - perhaps Nginx is getting overrided by my Node/ExpressJS server somehow?

Comment: There can't be two services listening to the same port, so one of them is not really running. BTW, redirecting to https:// without specifiying a port actually points to port 443.

Comment: Oh really? I'm totally new to Nginx and this sort of thing, can you suggest some code to fix it?

Answer (score -3):

```
app.configure(function () {
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.configure('production', function () {
    app.use (function (req, res, next) {
      var schema = (req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] || '').toLowerCase();
      if (schema === 'https') {
        next();
      } else {
        res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.url);
      }
    });
  });
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
  app.use(express.favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
});
```

Comment: Your answer is not formatted correctly and you need to add in some explanation as to what you're doing instead of just pasting in some code. What have you done here and why?

Comment: Also `app.configure()` doesn't exist in Express 4.0